# Designing an assignment for multithreading programming

Tags: multithreading

This semester I'm a TA of a OS course. So I was asked to design an assignment of multithread programming for CS undergraduates with limited C programming skills

This shouldn't be a large assignment because it only takes 5% of the final grade.  And this should be something new so students couldn't just download some code from Internet.

Here's what I'm thinking, a simple Message Queue sever.

> We will provide student a very dummy MQ sever which only has one
>   thread and accepts only 2 client connections, a reader and a writer. 
>   The writer periodically send message to the queue, i.e. the sever, and
>   the reader reads message from the queue, i.e. the sever sends the
>   message to the reader.  We will also provide the reader and
>   the writer.
>
> Then we ask the students to modify the sever to accept multiple
>   readers and writers at the same time.  And we will also ask for thread
>   safety. In other words, a message should only be sent one reader, and
>   no message is lost in the queue, that requires using of mutex.

I feel that it might be too simple but I couldn't think of anything else at this moment.  If you were in my position, what assignment will you give?

Comment: I took an OS class, not too long ago. They modeled the curriculum off of the stanford pintos OS class. This is probably too big of a change from what you guys are planning, but maybe you should consider it for next year. http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/pintos_2.html

Edit: By the way, this was my favorite class in the whole CS major by far. I felt like I really gained an understanding of the underlying OS architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Unix? Not that it matters, you can use Windows for this as well.

Simply, create a named pipe.

Then create 4 Threads.

1 control thread, 1 consumer (reader) thread, and 2 producer (writer) threads.

The producers simply send a string to the pipe, and the consumer takes the string, uppercases it or something and prints it out.

The control thread is used to start and stop the other 3 threads. It takes simple commands: startProducer1, startProducer2, startConsumer, stop commands, and a shut down command.

This shows the different threads all working on their own, but at the same time being controlled by the master (knowing when to shut down, etc.).

Bonus points if you can wrap this is a simple GUI, or even some simple Ncurses video display so that the control display always has visibility to accept the commands and display the results.

You can show if you start 1 producer but no consumers, how the thread will block. Same with both producers, or how the consumer blocks with no producers.

Using the pipe means you don't have to rely on that external program (and all the details of setting it up, debugging it configuring it and supporting it).

Both Unix and Windows have named pipes (but system calls I think are different, but POSIX portability may Just Work here...).

Answer (score 0):

you can have Connection pool manager at its primitive stage which just create a pool of connection and is reliably able to use and reuse a connection object.

Secondly you can have a httpclient which can perform multiple  GET only requests (as other will make it too complex), and you should be able to verify all the responses corresponding to each request (also you can make it for cancelling the request).

Thirdly the most simplest write a plain server socket which can accept each different request and assign it to new server thread get the request done and return back the response.

thats what I can think off..

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of classic problems such as [Dining Philosphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) is that deadlock and starvation are easy to demonstrate without getting deep into implementation details.

If you really need something original, try to choose a project where it's easy to foresee concurrency pitfalls. This way students are likely to run into them and get more out of the assignment. Otherwise, reformulate one of the classic problems so it's different enough from existing internet solutions but still the same in essence.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to ask the students to provide a threaded state machine for accessing critical sections, for example, to a robot arm.

e.g. the robot arm thread would contain public methods like “MoveArm(double position)”, and “StopArm()” etc. all of which would post signals to the robot arm’s signal queue. The robot arm thread would monitor the queue and pull the signals off one at a time and act accordingly, leaving other requests queued up for the next sequence of state transitions. Does this make sense?

This demonstrates how to serialise access to not just critical sections, but to critical sequence of actions.

E.g. MoveArm called from thread 1 (e.g. UI) would be posted on the robot arms signal queue, and once the robot arm thread detects the signal in its own thread, would move through the following states from ReadyState:

1. StartingToMoveArmState
2. MovingArmState (here we can listen for StopArm signals (e.g. if we have to e-stop etc.)
3. ReadyState(once move complete).

Thread 2 could whilst the robot arm thread is processing thread 1’s request to move the arm, call StopArm() – and this would be handled in the MovingArmState. Also, thread 2 could ask the arm to move elsewhere, but the robot arm thread would not service it until it was back in ReadyState. I.e. ReadyState will only de queue the next signal to move.

So therefore, the signal queue needs to be thread safe, and locked whenever threads 1 or 2 adds a signal to it. Also, the signal queue needs to set the robot arm thread to unblock so it can then inspect this signal and act accordingly (using e.g. a manual reset event).

Hopefully this may be useful!